# Getting WebRTC working (how to debug ICE Fail?)

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I can't figure out how to debug WebRTC. I keep getting 'ICE Failed' errors, but I doubt that's the issue. Here's my code: https://github.com/wamoyo/webrtc-cafe/tree/master/2.1%20Establishing%20a%20Connection%20%28within%20a%20Local%20Area%20Network%29

I'm using node.js/express/socket.io for setting up rooms and connecting peers, and then some default public servers for signalling.

The strange thing is, it appears the I have the remoteStream on the client.

Here's the two errors I'm getting (By they way, for now, I'm just trying to connect form my phone to laptop or two browser tabs, all within a LAN):

`HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://192.168.1.2:3000/%5Bobject%20MediaStream%5D failed.`

`ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details`

Any help would rock!

Comment: So starting debug mode in "about:webrtc" in firefox does not get you anything? What does your connection log say?

Comment: Hmmm... lots of errors: all checks completed success=0 fail=2, No STUN servers specified, No TURN servers specified, duplicate priority 1686110207 candidate ,

Comment: You're not setting the remoteVideo.src URL correctly on line 104. You should use window.URL.createObjectURL() like you do for the local stream.

Comment: Quick edit. ....word up! hold on...

Comment: Okay, that helps, but still no luck. That explains the content-type error, though, thanks so much!

Comment: I can't see that you're passing any constraints to enable audio/video to the createOffer() or createAnswer() calls. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC/WebRTC_basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a few comments already, but I think it's also worthwhile to write an answer.

There are 3 big things I see after my first quick read of your code. I haven't tried to actually run or debug your code beyond a superficial reading.

First, you should set the `remoteVideo.src` URL parameter in the same way as you do the local video stream:

```
pc.onaddstream = function(media) { // This function runs when the remote stream is added.
    console.log(media);
    remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(media.stream);
}
```

Second, you should pass a constraints object to the `createOffer()` and `createAnswer()` methods of `RTCPeerConnection`. The constraints should/could look like this:

```
var constraints = {
    mandatory: {
        OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
        OfferToReceiveVideo: true
    }
};
```

And you pass this after the success and error callback arguments:

```
pc.createOffer(..., ..., constraints);
```

and:

```
pc.createAnswer(..., ..., constraints);
```

Lastly, you are not exchanging ICE candidates between your peers. ICE candidates can be part of the offer/answer SDP, but not always. To ensure that you send all of them, you should implement an `onicecandidate` handler on the `RTCPeerConnection`:

```
pc.onicecandidate = function (event) {
    if (event.candidate) {
        socket.emit("ice candidate", event.candidate);
    }
}
```

You will have to implement "ice candidate" message relaying between clients in your server.js

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Walking through this now, just going to make some comments here... `Mandatory/optional in createOffer options is deprecated! Use {"offerToReceiveAudio":true,"offerToReceiveVideo":true} instead (note the case difference)!` according to Firefox.

Comment: Also, what about addIceCandidate? Is that needed? Can I send the ice candidate along with rest of the offer? What do I need to do with the ice candidate when it gets to the receiving end? I'm reading through the spec: http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/ as well as the mdn article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC/WebRTC_basics#ICECandidate, great resources, quite dense...

Comment: So it seems I've got `Invalid candidate passed to addIceCandidate()` I'm going to push  up my change and continue working on this.

Comment: Constraints should be 
    contraints = {
                  'offerToReceiveAudio': (mode !== 'sendonly'), 
               'offerToReceiveVideo': (mode !== 'sendonly')
              }